# mysql if select is my id don't return any rows

Tags: mysql

I have a bids table, id, sellerId, buyerId, notifId amount ....
if my id (sellerId) exists and doesn't exist for a notifId i don't want to return any rows
So my sellerId is 50001 and i have bid on notifId 1260, return no result, thats fine i can do that, but it will return the row for sellerid 1442 with same notifid.
I don't want to return anything if my id exists for any row with the same notifid
Hope that's as clear as mud.

```
SELECT n.notifId, n.senderId, n.sellerTypeId, n.subject, ur.model, n.message, n.firstname, n.lastname, n.email, n.days, n.created_date, DATE_ADD( n.created_date, INTERVAL n.days
DAY ) AS  'dateExpires', n.requestId, ur.subCategoryId, ur.item, ur.addressStreet, ur.addressCity, ur.addressState, ur.addressZip, ur.addressAlt, ur.tvscreen, ur.tvtype, ur.tvmount, ur.dvdregion, ur.dvdusb, ur.soundtype, ur.soundwireless, ur.createdDate,
            ur.gametype, ur.fridgesize, ur.fridgeheight, ur.fridgewidth, ur.fridgedepth, ur.fridgetype, ur.fridgeexterior,
            ur.washsize, ur.washheight, ur.washwidth, ur.washdepth, ur.washtype, ur.washexterior, DATEDIFF( DATE_ADD( n.created_date, INTERVAL n.days
DAY ) , NOW( )+ INTERVAL 0 HOUR ) AS daysLeft, TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR , NOW( )+ INTERVAL 0 HOUR , DATE_ADD( n.created_date, INTERVAL n.days
DAY ) ) AS hoursLeft,
TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE , NOW( )+ INTERVAL 0 HOUR , DATE_ADD( n.created_date, INTERVAL n.days
DAY ) ) AS minutesLeft, u.phoneNumber, ur.hasBid, ur.numItems, ur.electricity, ur.gas, ur.solar, ur.concession, ur.phone,
b.amount, COALESCE(b.bidAccepted, 0) AS bidAccepted, b.amount, b.powerCents, b.powerFee, b.powerDiscount, b.gasCents, b.gasFee, b.gasDiscount, b.additionalInfo, COALESCE(b.isLowestBid, 0) as isLowestBid, uri.imageName, ura.fileName, ih.address as homeinsaddress, ih.built, ih.propertyValue, ih.dwelling, ih.insurance, ih.moving, ih.owner, ih.previousClaimSelected as homeClaimSelected, ih.previousClaim as homeClaim, ih.requiredby as homeinsrequiredby,
ic.registration, ic.carmake, ic.carmodel, ic.caryear, ic.carfinance, ic.damage, ic.insured, ic.insurerName, ic.modifications, ic.modsValue, ic.nonstandard, ic.theftdevice, ic.gender, ic.garaged, ic.address as caraddress, ic.insType, ic.useType, ic.useFor, ic.age, ic.dob, ic.licenceYear, ic.estValue, ic.previousClaimSelected, ic.previousClaim, ic.licenceSuspended, ic.additionalDrivers, ic.requiredby as carinsrequiredby,
ip.petname, ip.petbreed, ip.petdesexed, ip.petgender, ip.pettype, ip.petborn, ip.petrequiredby, ip.petEstValue, ip.previousClaimSelected as petClaimSelected, ip.previousClaim as petClaim,
 h.address as healthaddress, h.covered, h.coverfor, h.income, h.rebate, h.yearbirth, h.requiredby as healthrequiredby, h.preExisting, h.healthPrimary, ur.categoryId, ur.subCategoryId, f.id as flightId, f.class, f.departure, f.departureDate, f.destination, f.oneWay, f.passengers, f.adults, f.children, f.cheapestFare, f.stopOvers, f.departureTime, f.layover, f.numNights, f.rating, f.details, f.returnDate,
hc.id as hireCarId, hc.driverAge, hc.dropoffDateTime, hc.dropoffLocation, hc.pickup, hc.pickupDateTime, hc.purpose, hc.vehicleType, c.id as cameraId, c.cameraType, c.cameraBrand, c.compactType, c.touchScreen, c.tiltable, c.wifi, c.waterProof, c.memoryCard, c.externalFlash, c.cameraCase, c.extraBattery, c.details as cameraDetails, COALESCE(r.id, 0) as ratingId, tt.taxiType
FROM notifications n
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON u.id = n.senderId
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_request ur ON ur.id = n.requestId

LEFT OUTER JOIN bids b ON b.notifId = n.notifId
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_request_images uri ON b.sellerId = uri.userId
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_request_attachments ura ON b.sellerId = ura.userId

LEFT OUTER JOIN insurance_home ih ON ur.id = ih.requestId
LEFT OUTER JOIN insurance_car ic ON ur.id = ic.requestId
LEFT OUTER JOIN insurance_pets ip ON ur.id = ip.requestId
LEFT OUTER JOIN insurance_health h ON ur.id = h.requestId
LEFT OUTER JOIN recreation_flights f ON ur.id = f.requestId
LEFT OUTER JOIN recreation_hirecar hc ON ur.id = hc.requestId
LEFT OUTER JOIN ratings r ON ur.id = r.requestId
LEFT OUTER JOIN taxi_types tt ON ur.taxiTypeId = tt.taxiTypeId
LEFT OUTER JOIN camera c ON ur.id = c.requestId
WHERE  (n.sellerTypeId = sellerTypeId and COALESCE(b.bidAccepted, 0) = bidsWon
    AND (FIND_IN_SET(ur.subCategoryId, _subCategories) )
```

and NOT EXISTS
            (
            SELECT  null
            FROM    notification_hide nh
            WHERE   nh.notifId = n.notifId and nh.sellerId = sellerId
            ))

```
    AND TIMESTAMPDIFF( SECOND , NOW( )+ INTERVAL 0 HOUR , DATE_ADD( n.created_date, INTERVAL n.days
    DAY ) ) > -0 group by n.notifId ORDER BY hoursLeft ASC
```

[image: Bids table]

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding, especially the part about "if my sellerId exists and doesn't exist for a notifId"... can you post your current SELECT statement? What field do you already know and what field are you trying to retrieve? Since you say it will return the row for sellerId 1442 with the same notifId, does that mean you know the notifId? Are you looking for something like this:

SELECT * FROM bids_table WHERE notifId = 1260 AND sellerId = 50001

Comment: Hi, have added the query

Comment: Hi, have added the query. I display 2 tables in php, table 1 contains no bids or bids from other sellers, table 2 contains only my bids. If another seller bids on one of my bids i end up with a row in each table. I don't want to display anyone elses bids in table one if i already have a bid on it ( same notifId)